# Nilpotent Subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The question is : Show that the nilpotent elements of a commutative ring form a subring.

Here is my unsuccessful take on it:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $S = \{a \in R | a^n = 0 \}$  be the set of nilpotent elements from $R$. Now, $0 \in S$, since $0^1 =0$. Hence $S$ is nonempty.

Let $x,y \in S$, then for some positive integers $n$ and $m$ we have $x^n=0$ and $y^m=0$. So far so good. 
Now we try to show that $(x + y)^k = 0$, for some positive integer k. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Hint: try k=n+m, expand with binomial theorem and argue that for each term, one of the exponents is big enough.

Comment: but big enough for what?

Comment: Wait, I think I have got it. Will try to solve and post solution.

Comment: The proposed duplicate resolves the sum of nilpotent elements being nilpotent (in a manner similar to Mathemagician's Hint).  However it doesn't address the multiplicative requirements to be a subring.  Although the assumption of commutativity quickly resolves closure under multiplication, it fails to provide a multiplicative identity.  Indeed the multiplicative identity is not a nilpotent element of a commutative ring, so apart from the dubious case 0=1, the proposition is always false.  It would be more acceptable to say the nilpotent elements form an ideal rather than a subring.